# Is it possible to set the first image from a gallery as the product image, rather than the featured image?

Tags: functions, woocommerce-offtopic

I'm trying to replace the featured image of related products (woocommerce) with the first image from the product's gallery. Basically I don't want to affect the products in general (shop page). I want this setting to be applied only for featured products.

Comment: You'll have to check with WooCommerce's support team. Third-party plugin support is [off topic](/help/on-topic) here.